# undeclared identifier error occurs when I already have declared the variable

Tags: c

I got an undeclared identifier error from the follow code, but i have clearly declared  the variable "length" in both cases. what did I do wrong?

```
int startWordLenRec(char s[]) {
    if (isLetter(s) == false){
        int length = 0;
    }
    else if{
        int length = 1 + startWordLenRec(s+1);
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if that is your construct it is perfectly valid to insert return statements where you do assignment. For instance `return 0` instead of `int length = 0` and then `return length` later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A declaration is local to the scope you declare it in.  So if you declare it inside `{}`, it cannot be used after the closing `}`.

```
int startWordLenRec(char s[]) {
    int length;
    if (isLetter(s) == false){
        length = 0;
    }
    else if{
        length = 1 + startWordLenRec(s+1);
    }
    return length;
}
```

Of course, you can also `return 0;` directly, without a separate variable.

Answer (score 4):

You've declared two variables in two different blocks, but then tried to use them outside of those blocks. Instead you want to declare *one* variable, and assign a value to it within each of the blocks:

```
int startWordLenRec(char s[]) {
    int length;
    if (isLetter(s) == false){
        length = 0;
    }
    else {
        length = 1 + startWordLenRec(s+1);
    }
    return length;
}
```

(I removed the extraneous "if" from after the "else".)

However, a conditional expression would be clearer (IMO):

```
int startWordLenRec(char s[]) {
    return isLetter(s) ? 1 + startWordLenRec(s+1) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of length outside of the if statement.  The way your currently have it declared it ceases to exit after the if statement executes so return length is always undeclared

Answer (score 1):

Declare length outside of the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

`length` needs to be declared at the top, since it is used in both branches of the if and outside (in the return statement).

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable "length" **inside** first and second if statements. Thus, it is not visible outside if statements